# Ubuntu 16.10 VM freezing after package updates

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, 16.10

I have an Ubuntu 16.10 virtual machine (VMWare). I ran an upgrade as usual using `sudo apt-get upgrade` and it downloaded packages fully and installed successfully. Then after a reboot the virtual machine froze, and it is not letting me to go to options window (Recovery console, memtest).

Please let me know if you need more information, thanks!

[image: screenshot from host, boot messages with OK status]

Comment: Does your image show where the system freezes, or does it get further in the boot process? Are you able to see the GRUB menu on power up?

Comment: @heynnema thanks for the reply, yes, I took this screenshot at the time virtual machine gets freeze, no further process, no I am not able to see GRUB, please help me!

Comment: See my answer, below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

Since you can't get to the Recovery screen, you'll have to boot to a Ubuntu Live image and do the following...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB (image in your case)
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`